# Is this a right way to find in nested type that a user has done an event e1 'n' times and has not done another event e2?

Tags: elasticsearch

I always get wrong result when I use must_not in bool. I think, I am creating a wrong query. Does anybody knows how I get user which 4 times done e1 event and not done any e2 event.
Below is Mapping of type user with nested event.

```
 {  
   "beta":{  
      "mappings":{  
         "user":{  
            "dynamic_templates":[  
               {  
                  "string_template":{  
                     "mapping":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "index":"analyzed",
                        "analyzer":"string_lowercase"
                     },
                     "match":"*",
                     "match_mapping_type":"string"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "_routing":{  
               "required":true,
               "path":"_shardId"
            },
            "properties":{  
               "event":{  
                  "type":"nested",
                  "properties":{  
                     "_date":{  
                        "type":"date",
                        "format":"dateOptionalTime"
                     },
                     "count":{  
                        "type":"long"
                     },
                     "first_date":{  
                        "type":"date",
                        "format":"dateOptionalTime"
                     },
                     "name":{  
                        "type":"string",
                        "analyzer":"string_lowercase"
                     },
                     "last_date":{  
                        "type":"date",
                        "format":"dateOptionalTime"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the query which you have already tried and didn't give you the expected result ?

Comment: GET  /jal/user/_search?routing=1&q=_id:54e5dc4817cf03cbbbe490e5
{"from":0,"size":1,"filter":{"and":[{"query":{"nested":{"path":"event","query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"event.name":'e1'}},{"match":{"event.count":4}}]}}}}},{"query":{"nested":{"path":"event","query":{"bool":{"must_not":{"match":{"event.name":e2}}}}}}}]}}

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have 2 query nodes?

And since you are using exact matches, you are better off with filter than query from performance perspective and caching.

Can you try this ?

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
        "filter" : {
            "nested" : {
                "path" : "event",
                "filter" : {
                    "bool" : {
                        "must" : [
                            {
                                "event.name":'e1'
                            },
                            {
                                "event.count":4
                            }
                        ]
                        "must_not" : {
                            "match" : {
                            "event.name" : "e2"
                            }
                         }
                    }
                },
                "_cache" : true
            }
        }
    }
}
```